# What is the logic with Sam's short pants?

Tags: plot-explanation, stay

In [Stay (2005)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_%282005_film%29), in the whole dream sequence Sam wears little short pants, which does not suit his personality. What is with it? Is this just a hint for it being a dream or is there any symbolism behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [MTV interview](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1512011/stay-not-meant-trick.jhtml), Marc Forster says -

> "When [McGregor] kneels down to talk to
>   Ryan [at the accident], Ryan's perception is that the pants are up, so
>   they're shorter. That's why Ewan's wearing shorter pants. And that's
>   why visual clues have a meaning throughout the film."